# Pin application to panel in Xfce on Xubuntu: Read/Set GValue

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, firefox, xfce

I want to pin an application (Firefox) to my Xfce panel on Xubuntu 18.04. So I used `xconf-query` to watch the panel channel for changes before I pinned Firefox and got the following output:

```
$ xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -m -v
Überwachung von Kanal »xfce4-panel« wird gestartet:

(xfconf-query:10987): xfconf-common-WARNING **: 09:40:17.839: Unable to convert GValue to string
einstellen: /plugins/plugin-12/items ((null))
einstellen: /plugins/plugin-12 (launcher)

(xfconf-query:10987): xfconf-common-WARNING **: 09:40:17.841: Unable to convert GValue to string
einstellen: /panels/panel-0/plugin-ids ((null))

(xfconf-query:10987): xfconf-common-WARNING **: 09:40:18.647: Unable to convert GValue to string
einstellen: /plugins/plugin-12/items ((null))
```

The main configuration like the path to the app seems to be in `/plugins/plugin-12/items` but its not possible to see what's inside this key:

```
$ xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -l -v | grep 12
/plugins/plugin-12                           launcher
/plugins/plugin-12/items                     <<UNSUPPORTED>>
```

So there are two questions:

1. How can I see what's inside the `GValue` of `/plugins/plugin-12/items`?
2. How is it possible to set this value?

My target is to solve this using [Ansibles xconf module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/xfconf_module.html#xfconf-module), but for understand and creating a first POC `xfconf-query` is fine (if possible).

#### Edit: `xfce4-settings-editor` offers read-only view

Using `xfce4-settings-editor` as suggested in the comments, I was able to view the `items` property. But it's not possible to edit it even manually when executing as root, the button is grayed-out where it works on other properties:

[image]

Comment: You should be able to look at the data for unsupported items within the xfce4-settings-editor. I don't know for certain if you can then take that and use it programmatically. I haven't tested that.

Comment: @KevinBowen This seems to work for a read-only view. But it seems not possible to edit such a property, even not in the GUI (see edited screenshot in the question).

Comment: Correct. But you can take that identifier and then go into ./config/panel/launcher-12/157804171.desktop and edit if you wish. I believe that you need to stop xfconf before editing. This is consider risky however.